# Getting Gregorian Calendar Week Numbers (Similar to Excel) in R

Tags: r, date, calendar, numbers

How do I get the following results in R?

| Date | Week Number |
| --- | --- |
| 12-27-2020 | 53 |
| 12-28-2020 | 53 |
| 12-29-2020 | 53 |
| 12-30-2020 | 53 |
| 12-31-2020 | 53 |
| 1-1-2021 | 1 |

In other words, I want Sunday to be the first day of the week and the last day of the year included in the last week. aka week 53.

Comment: Could you please check if this works for you `lubridate::isoweek(as.Date(df$Date,'%m-%d-%Y'))`?

Comment: Thank you for sharing. Not quite. 

This method treats Monday as Day 1 and includes Jan 1st through Jan 3rd of 2021 also in week 53...

Comment: @Roham The `%U` uses the `Sunday as Day 1` `format(as.Date(df1$Date, "%m-%d-%Y"), '%U')`

Comment: I believe it depends of the year. Technically, january 4 of 2021 is in the first week of 2021.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gives the same values as in the question:

```
ch <- c("12-27-2020", "12-28-2020", "12-29-2020", "12-30-2020", "12-31-2020", "1-1-2021")
d <- as.Date(ch, "%m-%d-%Y")
as.numeric(format(d, "%U")) + 1
## [1] 53 53 53 53 53  1
```

Also there is

- `as.numeric(format(d, "%V"))`
- `lubridate::isoweek(d)`
- `ISOweek::ISOweek(d)`

but they don't give the same result as in the question.